# How can we use jquery plugin like jquery.tabulator in angular 5 project

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-plugins

[enter image description here][1]

[enter image description here][2]

If I want to add the jQuery plugin like jquery.tabulator to angular project then how can we do that? as i did add the plugin js code in angula.cli.json file       "scripts": [

```
    "assets/libraries/tabulator/tabulator-min.js",
```

but when I use the tabulator initializing function to initialize it then it is giving an error. Property 'tabulator' does not exist on type 'JQuery

Comment: [Please don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2745495). Add and **[format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)** them into the post itself as **text**. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I added tags but as it stands this question really needs you to put in actual code you tried and add clarity - attempt to post an actual working example (even if it has errors) if at all possible please so we can help fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. install jquery, jquery-ui and jquery.tabulator

   `npm install jquery jquery-ui-dist jquery.tabulator --save`
2. install typings for jquery, used by typescript, save to dev
   dependencies

   `npm install @types/jquery --save-dev`
3. add jquery in `tsconfig.app.json` file

   ```
   ...
   "types": [
     "jquery"
   ]
   ...
   ```
4. include jquery and the plugin script in `.angular-cli.json`

   ```
   ...
   "styles": [
     "styles.css",
     "../node_modules/jquery.tabulator/dist/css/tabulator.min.css"
   ],
   "scripts": [
     "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
     "../node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.js",
     "../node_modules/jquery.tabulator/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"
   ]
   ...
   ```
5. add an interface JQuery in your local typings declaration file `typings.d.ts` and declare plugin function

   ```
   interface JQuery {
     tabulator(options1?: any, options2?:any): any;
   }
   ```
6. use tabulator as usual

---

Here's a reference link, [Angular 5 — using jquery plugins](https://medium.com/all-is-web/angular-5-using-jquery-plugins-5edf4e642969)